# Veeam unexpected "health check" for backup copy job

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, veeam, offsite-backup

In Veeam we have a `backup copy job` for creating offsite backups on usb disks.

Now I see that Veeam performs a `health check` on the usb disk.

[image: Veeam health check backup copy job]

I can't find any possibility to configure `health check` for copy jobs (Only for regular backup jobs as described here: [Veeam documentation](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/backup_health_check.html?ver=95))

The windows system eventlog does not show any errors for the disk.

**Edit**
There is no unexpected cancelation in the history of the backup copy jobs.

**Questions:**

- May the health check indicate that Veeam found an error on the usb disk?
- Can health checks be configured for backup copy jobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please examine the Veeam backup job settings.

The image below shows where the health check can be configured.

[image]